# How to refresh a page every 60 seconds to reload mysql query

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this code which reload the mysql conection  and shows resultset in a html table.
i want to refresh this page every 60 seconds so that new data shows in the page, currently manual refresh works but needs to make it automated.

i am using browser-refresh, but not sure how to set every 60 seconds, or if there is any other way to do this

I am using browser-refresh

`<script src="{process.env.BROWSER_REFRESH_URL}"></script>`
and

```
if (process.send) {
           process.send('online');
       }
```

My codes follows :-

```
const http = require('http');
const mysql = require('mysql');

const pool = mysql.createPool({
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'root',
  password: '',
  database: 'alerts',
  charset: 'utf8'
});


var reo ='<html><head><title>POWER CUT ALERT</title></head><body><h1>POWER CUT ALERT</h1>{${table}}   <script src="{process.env.BROWSER_REFRESH_URL}"></script> </body></html>';



function setResHtml(sql, cb){
  pool.getConnection((err, con)=>{
    if(err) throw err;

    con.query(sql, (err, res, cols)=>{
      if(err) throw err;

      var table =''; //to store html table

      //create html table with data from res.
      for(var i=0; i<res.length; i++){
        table +='<tr><td>'+ (i+1) +'</td><td>'+ res[i].timestamp +'</td><td>'+ res[i].device_id +'</td></tr>';
      }
      table ='<table border="1"><tr><th>Nr.</th><th>Timestamp</th><th>IMEI NO</th></tr>'+ table +'</table>';

      con.release(); //Done with mysql connection
      con.destroy();

      return cb(table);
    });
  });
}

let sql ='SELECT * from alerts';

const server = http.createServer((req, res)=>{
    setResHtml(sql, resql=>{
        var reo2 = reo.replace('{${table}}', resql);
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type':'text/html; charset=utf-8'});
        res.write(reo2, 'utf-8');
        res.end();

        if (process.send) {
            process.send('online');
        }

  });
});



server.listen(8080, ()=>{
  console.log('Server running at //localhost:8080/');
});
```

Comment: Maybe you can use a [setTimeout](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) function

Comment: @juan Scolari , where do put that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use `setInterval` for that purpose.

```
setInterval(function () { 
    //Call the server api
}, 1000 * 60);
```

**Browser-refresh** has different purpose:

> This module improves productivity by enabling instant web page
>   refreshes anytime a front-end resource is modified on the server.

Basically (very similar to nodemon) it tracks changes in file system and supports live reloading of CSS and JavaScript.